# How can I force my calculated covariance matrix to be positive definite? _LinAlgError: linalg.cholesky

Tags: python, pytorch, data-analysis, linear-algebra, gaussian-process

I am attempting to use Gaussian process regression to estimate a function with two inputs and one output. I know the following about my function:

1. if x1 == x2, then f(x1, x2) = 0
2. if f(x1, x2) = y, then f(x2, x1) = -y

My goal is to find a covariance function that captures this information. The covariance function should take in two 2D inputs, and return how correlated their y-values are expected to be. The form I decided on was:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import torch
from scipy.special import expit
import gpytorch
from gpytorch.kernels import ScaleKernel, RBFKernel


def true_eff_func(x, sig_cent = 12, gauss_cent = 12): #Helper function

    def gauss(x, amp = 0.2, cen = 12, sig = 1):
        return amp * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2 * sig**2))
    
    return 0.4 * expit((x - sig_cent) / 2) + 1.2 * gauss(x, cen = gauss_cent) + 0.05


def g(x1, x2): #Function I am trying to model
    return np.log(true_eff_func(x1) / true_eff_func(x2))


def covar(x1, x2):
    #x1.shape == x2.shape == (N, 2)
    
    def tilt_sig(x, y):
        return 2 * (expit(y - x) - 0.5)
    
    def gaussian(x, y, length = 3):
        return np.exp(-(x ** 2 + y ** 2) / (2 * length ** 2))
    
    x1_sig = tilt_sig(x1[:, 1], x1[:, 0])
    x2_sig = tilt_sig(x2[:, 1], x2[:, 0])
    
    gauss_no_flip = gaussian(x1[:, 0] - x2[:, 0], x1[:, 1] - x2[:, 1])
    gauss_flip    = gaussian(x1[:, 0] - x2[:, 1], x1[:, 1] - x2[:, 0])
    
    return x1_sig * x2_sig * np.amax(np.vstack([gauss_no_flip, gauss_flip]), axis = 0)
```

This has the desirable qualities of having points on opposite sides of the line x1 = x2 being negatively correlated and correlation when one of the points is on the line x1 = x2.

However, if I generate some dummy test_data and try and fit my function:

```
minx, maxx = 4, 20
n_samples = 100
x1 = np.random.random(n_samples) * (maxx - minx) + minx
x2 = np.random.random(n_samples) * (maxx - minx) + minx
x_train = np.column_stack([x1, x2])

y_train = g(x_train[:,0], x_train[:, 1])

x_train = torch.tensor(x_train)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train) + torch.randn(x_train.shape[0]) * math.sqrt(0.01)

class EfficiencyGPModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super(EfficiencyGPModel, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
        #self.covar_module = ScaleKernel(RBFKernel())
    
    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        
        covar_rows = []
        for x1 in x:
            covar_row = eff_covar(x1[None, :], x)
            covar_rows.append(covar_row)
        covar_x = torch.Tensor(np.column_stack(covar_rows))
        print(np.linalg.eigvalsh(np.column_stack(covar_rows)))

        return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
    
likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.GaussianLikelihood()
model = EfficiencyGPModel(x_train, y_train, likelihood)
    
likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.GaussianLikelihood()
model = ExactGPModel(train_x, train_y, likelihood)



model.train()
likelihood.train()
training_iter = 100

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 0.1)

mll = gpytorch.mlls.ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(likelihood, model)

for i in range(training_iter):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    output = model(x_train)
    
    loss = -mll(output, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    
    print('Iter %d/%d - Loss: %.3f   lengthscale: %.3f   noise: %.3f' % (
        i + 1, training_iter, loss.item(),
        model.covar_module.base_kernel.lengthscale.item(),
        model.likelihood.noise.item()
    ))
    
    optimizer.step()
```

I get the following error: _LinAlgError: linalg.cholesky: The factorization could not be completed because the input is not positive-definite (the leading minor of order 52 is not positive-definite).

These are the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix:

```
[-1.10155085e-07 -9.27407697e-08 -7.29177358e-08 -6.52091003e-08
 -5.39412568e-08 -4.37013661e-08 -3.41021220e-08 -2.75051182e-08
 -2.49618939e-08 -1.15477574e-08 -5.44824896e-09 -3.41062761e-10
  1.01976454e-08  1.23503661e-08  2.26680896e-08  2.89906303e-08
  3.96474462e-08  4.27377671e-08  4.52128219e-08  5.65371039e-08
  7.08461485e-08  7.54759313e-08  8.33512104e-08  1.06643839e-07
  1.29051074e-07  1.54300437e-07  1.86617640e-07  2.35383439e-07
  2.81686340e-07  3.66409296e-07  6.42385203e-07  7.49586036e-07
  1.09072016e-06  1.14950092e-06  1.50481765e-06  1.60451987e-06
  2.56799194e-06  2.73187061e-06  3.09103439e-06  4.48133960e-06
  5.13697250e-06  6.04562820e-06  7.11317580e-06  7.68858717e-06
  1.43603129e-05  2.01654257e-05  2.25989315e-05  3.61687635e-05
  4.34386857e-05  5.12812730e-05  5.79993794e-05  7.19724776e-05
  9.53794079e-05  1.06705746e-04  1.57744682e-04  2.11907085e-04
  2.61359994e-04  3.21925123e-04  3.73442279e-04  5.40336128e-04
  6.22481923e-04  7.68499682e-04  1.07206043e-03  1.38637831e-03
  1.67397782e-03  2.03465600e-03  2.89701507e-03  3.22554773e-03
  4.04457189e-03  5.32198744e-03  6.59662718e-03  9.89408698e-03
  1.15479613e-02  1.31655317e-02  1.94454622e-02  2.50456035e-02
  2.86159441e-02  3.87079418e-02  5.64073287e-02  6.63131401e-02
  8.67272094e-02  8.85061622e-02  1.26840591e-01  1.65471166e-01
  2.08375335e-01  2.62104928e-01  3.12507421e-01  3.79930466e-01
  7.52925634e-01  8.89389396e-01  9.46783006e-01  1.29029942e+00
  2.44207215e+00  2.71784759e+00  3.66648054e+00  5.55810690e+00
  7.87740803e+00  1.02781000e+01  1.38569288e+01  2.81411953e+01]
```

So it makes sense that the Cholesky decomposition threw an error; some eigenvalues are negative. I am unsure what changes I can make to my covariance function to resolve this. Additionally, I see that the negative eigenvalues are (relatively small). Could these be numerical errors? If so, how can I avoid them?

One additional factor is that **I do not see this error when n_samples < 32**. I can run this code from start to finish and not see an error. With n_samples >= 50 however, this error pops up every time.